# A site built in .NET 3.5 to target 4.0, when server runs 3.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I have a legacy .NET site that has been around since the 1.1 days. As I've upgraded my VS, I've upgraded the target framework as well. Currently the site is running 3.5. I just got VS10 and it is asking me to upgrade the site to 4.0. However, my (shared) server is still running 3.5 and I can't upgrade it. Is it safe to upgrade the site to 4.0 while the server running it is 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I wouldn't think so.  All of your basic assembly information in your web.config will be changed to target the 4.0.0.0 versions of dll's and not the 3.5.0.0 versions.  As a result, you will generate a lot of missing assembly error messages.  PS - VS2010 should only prompt you once...

Answer (score 3):

No its not safe for you to upgrade, your website wont run.

When i upgraded to VS10 i forgot to upgrade my server. It was showing errors about the unknown tags VS10 adds during the upgrade process, which i imagine is just the start.